# How to configure XAMPP PHP to send mail from localhost via secure smtp my ISP

Tags: php, email, xampp, localhost

For sending email I normaly use Windows 7 Thunderbird with configuring secure SMTP via my ISP (i.e. login and password for SMTP server). Connection security: none, Password transmited insecurely. Mails are send OK.

I tried configure XAMPP php.ini

```
[mail function]
SMTP=*my_isp_smtp_server*
smtp_port=25
sendmail_from=*my_email_address*
sendmail_path="\"c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
mail.add_x_header = Off
```

and sendmail.ini

```
smtp_server=*smtp_server.my.isp*
smtp_port=25
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=*login_to_my_isp_smtp_server*
auth_password=*password_to_my_isp_smtp_server*
force_sender=*my_email_address*
```

In my php script I use standard php function:

```
mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I get no error message, but mail is not delivered.
Please could you help me anyone?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586801/send-email-by-using-codeigniter-library-via-localhost), haven't tried it myself yet, but the settings of this CodeIgniter question/answer might help you out. Comments there say that localhost will only work with Gmail. For all others you'll need live hosting (so no localhost).

Answer (score -1):

For everyone still struggling with this issue while looking for a solution, using **sendmail** package, you can configure it to use **SMTP** secure servers like **gmail**. For simplicity I will show down below an example using gmail servers, but you can set your own SMTP server using [hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com/) . Documentation is available [here](https://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/latest/?page=overview) and it uses port **465** for **TLS**. You just need to change, from the following gmail configuration, the **SMTP server**, **port**, **address** and **password**. The structure stays the same.

[image: hmailserver]

If you want to go for gmail route, as an example, check these parameters [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=it):
[image: gmailserver]

Understood so, make the following changes:

In `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` uncomment `extension=php_openssl.dll` and **restart Apache** to add **SSL** support. Also change these values as in the documentation guide and set `sendmail_from` accordingly:

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = yourgmailaddress@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

And in `C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini` mirror these changes:

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
auth_username=yourgmailaddress@gmail.com
auth_password=yourgmailpassword
force_sender=yourgmailaddress@gmail.com
```