# how to send email in codeiginter

Tags: codeigniter

I am beginner with codeiginter and I am not understanding how to send email. Please anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

```
$config = Array(
                'mailtype'  => 'html', 
                );
              $this->load->library('email', $config);
              $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
              $this->email->from('aaa@gmail.com', 'aaa');
              $this->email->to('bbb@gmail.com');  
              $this->email->subject('This is an email test');  
              $this->email->message('It is working. Great!');
              $result = $this->email->send();
              echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586801/send-email-by-using-codeigniter-library-via-localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com');
$this->email->cc('another@another-example.com');
$this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com');

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

$this->email->send();

echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

refrence #[Codeigniter Email](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from($from);
$this->email->to($to);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($mailContent);
($this->email->send())
```